# implementing loading gif image on a jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery

I red some articles and similar questions on stack overflow but didnt really find any simple clean solution to this problem.

for example this is my ajax function:

```
  $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/AddSong",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#AddTopTenFavForm").serialize(),
            success: function (data) { ShowMsg("Song Added Successfully"), $(container).find('ul').append('<li><a class="savedLinks" href="#" name="' + substr + '" >' + name + '</a> <span name= ' + data +' class="btnDeleteSong dontDoAnything">x</span></li>'); },
            error: function () { ShowMsg("There was an error therefore song could not be added, please try again") }
        });
```

I would like to call my functions:

```
 function ShowAjaxLoader() {
$("#dottedWrapper").fadeIn();
$("#loadingGifContainer").fadeIn();
}

 function HideAjaxLoader() {
$("#dottedWrapper").fadeOut(1000);
$("#loadingGifContainer").fadeOut(1000);
}
```

when Ajax request starts and when it finishes. Please help thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events this is what you need. Just add your function into the relivant event within the ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the show function before the ajax, then call the Hide function upon success or error

```
ShowAjaxLoader();
   $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/AddSong",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#AddTopTenFavForm").serialize(),
        success: function (data) { 
          HideAjaxLoader();
          ShowMsg("Song Added Successfully"), $(container).find('ul').append('<li><a class="savedLinks" href="#" name="' + substr + '" >' + name + '</a> <span name= ' + data +' class="btnDeleteSong dontDoAnything">x</span></li>'); },
        error: function () { 
          HideAjaxLoader();
          ShowMsg("There was an error therefore song could not be added, please try again") }
    });
```

Comment: Is this a recommended technique?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of jquery ajax events http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events

There are events such as beforeSend:, complete:, success:, error:

Just put your function calls within these events.

Answer (score 1):

Global settings that affect all ajax calls are defined with [$.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do it using [Ajax Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events). That way it happens on every ajax request you make (also if you choose to make more than one in different places, causing less code redundancy)

```
$("#loading").bind("ajaxSend", function(){
  ShowAjaxLoader();
}).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
  HideAjaxLoader();
});
```